Can we divide the story points across team members?
Lets assume that within a sprint a team of 4 developers delivers 28 story points.
Is it correct to state that each developer delivers 7 story points per sprint and use this information to base what 2 developers in the team can deliver i.e. 14 story points e.g. assuming the other 2 are on holidays?
My question is in terms of agile, because obviously working with team it is much clearer what is the performance and deliverables per developer which can be "unequal"

You could keep track of how many story points each dev finishes in the sprint on average

@Tvde1 that would still only work if developers only work on tasks alone and don't spend time helping each other. So basically a metric that's only useful if the team's already disfunctional.


Is it correct to state that each developer delivers 7 story points per sprint and use this information to base what 2 developers in the team can deliver i.e. 14 story points e.g. assuming the other 2 are on holidays?

No.
In a team of 1 senior developer, 1 mid level developer, one junior developer and one apprentice in their first year... are you really asking whether the team will complete the same amount of work, regardless of who takes a week off?
They don't. You didn't hire 4 identical robots.
If your team composition changes, your numbers become meaningless. You can still wager a good guess, but that's it.
The only occurrance where you can "calculate" with points and velocity is when your team remains unchanged, but the time changes. It is a good estimation, that if your sprint of 10 business days has one Monday of public holiday, then in 9 business days there will probably be 90% of the work done compared to a regular 10 day sprint.
Because team composition did not change and days are indeed equal and interchangeable units. People are not.

I've been on teams that gave everybody on the team equal points during sprints. It meant that I could complete all of my work for the sprint in 2 days, while others would struggle to finish their tickets in 2 weeks. So, in that team environment you could do what OP asks, but that's a stupid team environment that you shouldn't try to replicate.

You can't divide a team's velocity by the number of developers and get a meaningful per-developer velocity. One problem is what you say - developers are unequal, especially regarding their knowledge and experience, which gives them an advantage (or disadvantage) when taking on certain types of work. However, it also neglects cases where people work together to get the work done.
If your team is at half capacity, it could be a good starting point to think about planning half the work. But it's still a small piece of the puzzle.
